# Use multiple SearchableInfo in SearchView

Tags: android, searchview

I'm able to successfully implement the `SearchView` widget in the `ActionBar` and can search and launch applications easily.

I do this using this:

```
SearchManager mSearchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);

if (mSearchManager!=null) {
    List<SearchableInfo> searchables = mSearchManager.getSearchablesInGlobalSearch();

    for (SearchableInfo i:searchables) {
        Log.d("setupSearchView", i.getSuggestAuthority());

        if (i.getSuggestAuthority() != null && i.getSuggestAuthority().startsWith("com.android.contacts")) {
            mSearchView.setSearchableInfo(i);
            break;
        }
    }
```

However, I'd like to include add more `SearchableInfo` into the same `SearchView` object. The ones returned from the `SearchManager`. Something like Google Now search.